# Thread management - competing threads

Tags: java

I have a situation where my multi-threaded application is competing against each other. I have an initial startup method:

```
public void standAloneStartup(){
  try {
    this.startupComms();
  } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
          Logger.getLogger(ThinClientEngine.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
  }
  this.startupProcess();
  this.requestAllProjects();
}
```

Below is the `startupComms` method:

```
final synchronized void startupComms() throws InterruptedException{
   //Listen for connections
   this.tceServer = new Server(6300, this, "ThinClientEngineServer");
   te.execute(tceServer);
   this.tceServer.join();
   Info.Info(this.tceServer.getServerName() + " is running and can recieve connections...");
   //Connect to Application Server
   this.appClient = new Client("localhost", 6000, this, "AppEngineClientConnection");
   te.execute(appClient);
   this.appClient.join();
   Info.Info(this.appClient.getClientName() + " successfully connected...");
   }
```

As you can see I have tried making the method `synchronized` and I am also trying to `join` the thread so that the current doesn't process. From what I read the join method will wait until the thread finishes or the `notify` is called.

The sequence of events in the startup process is the following:

1. Startup a server to listen for connections
2. Startup a client to connect to the Server
3. Send a message to the Server

Now the second step creates a ServerConnection but by the time the third step is called, the ServerConnection instance is not created yet and is null.

This was all provoked because I realized I had some issues with my object stream that I was trying to fix. In the end I realized that I needed to ensure that the write and read object methods were synchronized which present this problem that I am having once I changed that.

`Server` and `Client` are extended from `Thread`. The `Server` starts a server socket via a `ClientConnection` with a while true loop for listening and accepting connections. The `Client` starts a `ServerConnection` which is also a thread. `te` is my `ThreadPoolExecutor`.

How can I make sure to wait for those previous threads before continuing?

If you would like to see whole classes, let me know and I will post the classes requested.

Comment: Hint: the net of my answer is: you have to put up a **real** [mcve]; containing all relevant code; instead of giving 30% of your code and explaining the rest. I think you have two choices now: A) rework this question ... or B) accept what you got, and come back with another, more specific question with that [mcve] part!

Comment: I agree - That problem is now resolved by just starting the thread instead of using the ThreadPoolExecutor. I do have another question that is now different to this one. So I will create a new question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the javadoc for [join()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join())

*Waits for this thread to die.*

So:

```
this.tceServer.join();
Info.Info(this.tceServer.getServerName() + " is running and can recieve connections...");
```

Sounds like a big contradiction. You wait for the server thread to **die**; and then you expect it to be available!

That explains why your code doesn't do what you expect it to do; your assumptions on A) what join() is doing and B) how the **run()** method of your Thread sub class behaves are both not accurate.

In order to **really** help with the underlying problem; you have to show us the **code** for that server class; and you would have to explain what exactly `te.execute(tceServer);` is supposed to do. Well, not explain; but provide that code here.

Comment: I added them in attempt to solve the problem. I removed them and just executed them without the `ThreadPoolExecutor` and that solved the null pointer issue. Unfortunately, I was overlooking the fact that I did not need to use the TPE.